# Condition to Skip Input field if Empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to set a condition wherein if the 'filefield' is empty, it will skip the insert in DB as it is only an option and just proceed in inserting of 'name' and 'description' in the DB, which will never be empty.

```js
<?php
include("connection.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);

if ($name == '' || $description == '' )
{

$error = 'ERROR: Please fill required fields!';

renderForm($name, $description);
}
else
{

if(!empty($_FILES['filefield'])){
if(isset($_FILES['filefield'])){
$file=$_FILES['filefield'];
$upload_directory='uploads/';
$ext_str = "gif,jpg,jpeg,mp3,tiff,bmp,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,txt,pdf";
$allowed_extensions=explode(',',$ext_str);
$ext = substr($file['name'], strrpos($file['name'], '.') + 1);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions) )
{

echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("file type not allowed for upload")';
echo '</script>';
exit(); 
}

$path=md5(microtime()).'.'.$ext;

if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$upload_directory.$path)){

    $filefield = $_FILES["filefield"]["name"];
    $path = $path."/".$filefield;
   }
 }
   }
}

 if (!empty($_FILES['filefield']) || !isset($_FILES['filefield'])) {
$query = "INSERT INTO `item`(`name`, `description`, `path`) VALUES ('$name','$description','$path')";
}
else {
$query = "INSERT INTO `item`(`name`, `description`) VALUES ('$name','$description')";
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 if($result)
    {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Success!")';
    echo '</script>';      
    exit();
}   
}
?>
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with the condition. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `if(empty($_FILES["filefield"]["name"])` ?

Comment: Hi @Raptor - the response of Obsidian Age is fairly close, only that it still inserting the $path together with the MD5 even the filefield is empty.

Answer (score 0):

First, close off all of your logic, including `if(move_uploaded_file)`, so that the `$query` is competely outside of any conditionals. Then it's just a matters of checking whether the `filefield` was filled out or not. If it's not empty, your `$query` insert all three fields. If it is, your `$query` only inserts `$name` and `$description`.

This can be seen in the following (heavily cut-down) code:

```
/* Existing logic */
else
{
    if (!empty($_FILES['filefield'])) {
        if (isset($_FILES['filefield'])) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_directory.$path)) {
               ...
               $path = $path."/".$filefield;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Modified logic */
if (!empty($_FILES['filefield']) || !isset($_FILES['filefield'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `item`(`name`, `description`, `path`) VALUES ('$name','$description','$path')";
}
else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `item`(`name`, `description`) VALUES ('$name','$description')";
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: Hello @Obsidian Age - I just tried it and still it won't accept if the filefield is empty. I've updated the code above to reflect the change. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Obsidian Age - I've revised it as you suggested and it's almost there. It can not insert the 'name' and 'description' field even if the filefield is empty, however the MD5 tag of  `$path = $path."/".$filefield;` gets inserted instead. I think its not falling in into the 'else' statement correctly, `else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `item`(`name`, `description`) VALUES ('$name','$description')"; ` It's trying to post the '$path' still.